# Can Pentax K mount lenses be used on a 645 Reflex via an adapter?

Tags: lens, pentax, lens-adapter, k-mount

Is it possible to use Pentax K mount lenses on a Pentax 645 via an adapter?  If so, what is the name and type of adaptor required?

Comment: I know you can go the other way, but K to 645 would be very odd given the image circle would be quite small on medium format film or sensors.

Answer (score 5):

**No.** Even, if someone would build an adapter it could not possibly fully work.

One normally adapts a lens for a larger format to a camera with a smaller format. Going the other way, as you suggest, would place a lens with a small imaging circle compared to your sensor or film and result in clipped edges. other words you would only the center which kind of negates the purpose of a larger format.

The other number to pay attention to  is the flange distance. You can bridge a gap for a  lens that requires a longer one but mounting it too far makes such lenses not able to focus past a few centimeters or less than a meter. This would happen if you placed a K-mount lens in front of a 645 mount camera.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that would be the scenario.  Appreciate the response and confirmation.